# Bouncy Castle Curve25519 private key from Scrypt output

Tags: java, bouncycastle, curve-25519

I am trying to achieve ECIES encryption, for which below code is working.

```
X9ECParameters ecP = CustomNamedCurves.getByName("curve25519");
ECParameterSpec ecSpec = EC5Util.convertToSpec(ecP);

BigInteger d = new BigInteger("145642755521911534651321230007534120304391871461646461466464667494947990");

ECPrivateKeySpec priKeySpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(
                    d, // d
                    ecSpec);
ECPoint Q = new FixedPointCombMultiplier().multiply(params.getG(), d.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(-1)));

Q = Q.normalize();

ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(
                    new ECPoint(Q.getAffineXCoord().toBigInteger(), Q.getAffineYCoord().toBigInteger()), // Q
                    ecSpec);

KeyFactory factTrial = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
BCECPrivateKey          sKey = (BCECPrivateKey) factTrial.generatePrivate(priKeySpec);
PublicKey           vKey = factTrial.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithAES-CBC",BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
byte[] encodeBytes = c.doFinal(data.getBytes());
String encrypt = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodeBytes);

Cipher c2 = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithAES-CBC",BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
c2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,sKey, c.getParameters()); 
byte[] decodeBytes = c2.doFinal(encodeBytes);
String deCrypt = new String(decodeBytes,"UTF-8");
```

*Issue is the private key element 'd'. If I try to replace it with output of scrypt hash, private key fails to be converted in PrivateKey instance.*

I have gone through net resources https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/251, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51703/how-to-convert-from-curve25519-33-byte-to-32-byte-representation, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72134/raw-curve25519-public-key-points.

Above resources suggest the way Bouncy Castle for Curve25519 interprets private key is different from the ways some internet resource suggest. In post https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51703/how-to-convert-from-curve25519-33-byte-to-32-byte-representation there is mention as follows.

> According to the curve25519 paper a x25519 public key can be represented in 32 bytes.
>
> The x25519 library I'm using (bouncycastle) however gives me a 33 byte representation according to this standard.

I am very new to ECC, these resources are confusing me, the difference between lengths, the style of encoding big vs. little.

> I have tried libSodium 'crypto_box_easy' and 'crypto_box_open_easy'
>   via its Java binding and it works all fine. The 32 byte scrypt output
>   is used by 'crypto_box_seed_keypair' to generate key pair which is
>   used for encryption process.

As I see some maths is involved here which I lack at present or I am failing to see the conversion.

**I have to go this route Scrypt output -> key pair -> use for encryption**

**Using directly KeyGenerator from BC is working, but that utilises SecureRandom, but I need the output of Scrypt to behave as private key.**

**Questions:**

1. I'll really appreciate someone helps me understand the difference between libSodium and Bouncy Castle approach. libSodium mentions it uses X25519. When I try to create X25519 key from 32 bytes, but BC Cipher(ECIESwithAES-CBC) then complaints it is not a EC Point, from this resource 'https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/251' it seems there are differences in that too (Curve25519 vs X25519).
2. The private key 'd', how to interpret it. I have seen these random values in Bouncy Castle documentation and test cases, is this simply a number in the prescribed range for valid keys? This number is treated (little vs. big endian) before creating BigInteger instance. I mean the raw value of 'd' in the my code example was converted from some other number?

The struggle between understanding different mechanism of Curve25519 and BC API itself, I am really confused.

Some pointers to further my research would be of great help.

Comment: Maybe you could better ask this at (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The private key `d` is just an integer in the prescribed range. I'm not sure what scrypt output you're talking about but if your output is bytes then you convert it to an integer in the prescribed range. Big endian or little endian can be your choice but it needs to be consistent between peers and supported by all the bigint libraries your are using. The format of the public key is not relevant, you need to be complying with the curve25519 constraints on the integer private key.